# ¿Cómo puedo crear una apk con Expo 27?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, expo

Llevo ya 2 días enteros perdidos intentando crear una apk de mi proyecto, actualmente tenemos un programa que funciona correctamente en el emulador de expo (utilizando la app de expo en el celular y leyendo el codigo QR), sin embargo, al momento de realizar el build:android y crear la apk esta se cierra automáticamente al intentar abrirla en el celular.

Luego de dos días de investigación, tengo 2 preguntas:

1. ¿Detach y eject son lo mismo?
2. Si mi programa funciona en el emulador de expo para android, ¿de todas maneras es posible que tenga que realizar detach/eject?

Ya he logrado generar una apk tanto utilizando expo (build:android) como utilizando detach/eject y buildeandolo en Android Studio, cabe mencionar que en esta ultima surgieron 2 errores con las siguientes soluciones:

1. Al hacer el detach/eject debo entrar en android/app/build.gradle y eliminar la linea trata de compilar :expoview (casi al final del archivo).
2. Debo crear por cuenta propia el folder android/detach-script junto con sus dos archivos correspondientes.

Versión Expo: 27.0.1